# Error: Id attribute is not allowed on the root tag of a component

Tags: apache-flex

I have a code like the one below

```
<mx:Button id="TestingID" width="100%" height="20">                   
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
             import flexlib.containers.WindowShade;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script-->
</mx:Button>
```

I am getting the error "id attribute is not allowed on the root tag of a component"

I have to give a Id to the button to refer to it. What should i do.. how do i solve this problem??

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are calling the component from within itself then you use the 'this' keyword.

```
<mx:Button height="20">                   
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
             import flexlib.containers.WindowShade;
             this.percentWidth = 100;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script-->
</mx:Button>
```

And if you want to refer to the custom component from your application then you do this.

```
<application xmlns:local = "[Directory containing custom component]">
    <local:MyCustomButton id="myButtonInstantiation" />
</application>
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

An MXML file is essentially a class.  So if you want to reference the instance of that class from within it then you just use "this".

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are nesting a component inside another

As soon as you use the `<fx:Component>` tag you are in the root of an mxml-inline-document

```
<mx:itemEditor>
    <fx:Component>
            <mx:TextInput id="precioVenta"/>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemEditor>
```

All you need to do is move the `id` attribute into the  tag like this

```
<mx:itemEditor>
    <fx:Component id="precioVenta">
        <mx:TextInput />
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemEditor>
```

This applies to any kind of tag or nesting that causes the Flex compiler to create a new context for the inlinde declaration of a component

Answer (score 0):

If you're defining this in a file as a subclass of `Button` then you can't set the `id` here. Put the id in the place you use this new component. For example, if this new component will be an `AwesomeButton`, you could use it like so:

```
<mycompnamespace:AwesomeButton id="testingId" />
```

Comment: I did not get it... will you plz explain a bit more

Comment: You should consider the book Programming Flex 3 so you can get familiar with the basics of Flex development (http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Flex-Comprehensive-Creating-Applications/dp/0596516215)

Answer (score 0):

Let see below code -

```
<s:ComboBox id="myCombo" dataProvider="{al}">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:CheckBox **id="NOWAY**" click="clickHandler(event)"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
</s:ComboBox>
```

id is not allowed in these sort of scenarios, you use of 'this' keyword, because in this context CheckBox is root tag within Component.